# Are there preconfigured libraries for video object recognition, in which I could pass in an mp4 into a function

Tags: python, object-detection

I have a video of me walking down a city street, can I pass that into a function that will then print what it sees (telephone pole, trash can, dog, ..ect)? What library could I use?

The key is I dont want to have to train the model (ie pass in a bunch of photos of trach cans or dogs ect)

(ideally python)

**SOLVED**
This article works great actually

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-simple-object-detection-system-with-python-and-imageai-ee1bcaf6b111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there are possibilities to do object detection in real time. For instance, YOLO in combination with darknet would maybe be a possibility to for you. For more information see: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/
and https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/wiki/YOLO:-Real-Time-Object-Detection

Comment: thank you! I actually do not need it to be real time, rather just want a good library where I can just pass in an mp4 and see everything that is is able to classify

Comment: if you dont need it in realtime I can also suggest you OpenAI. It works quite nicely.

Comment: what about https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-simple-object-detection-system-with-python-and-imageai-ee1bcaf6b111 ?